# Fonts too large. Where are all the places display scaling or dpi could be specified?

Tags: xorg, kde, display-settings, plasma5, fontconfig

I have more than one desktop computer running Arch Linux KDE. All were initially configured the same. Now one of them now has a scaled up display. I have not found the setting that is responsible for this.

Having checked every setting in KDE, I can say it is not a setting within KDE. **Which other settings or config files could be making font (and other display elements) too large?**

The text of messages during boot is normal. The problem starts once X starts.

My monitor has **109 ppi**. The problem is shown here:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dots
resolution:    192x191 dots per inch
```

I would like that value to be either 109 (to match monitor) or 96 (the usual Xorg value).

In System Settings > Display Configuration, the scale factor is 1.0.

In System Settings > Fonts I can check "Force font DPI" and set my desired value, **but it doesn't have any effect**. `xdpyinfo` still reports "192x191 dots per inch".

I do not have any Xorg config files:

```
/etc/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
/etc/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
```

I do not have anything unusual in `.fonts.conf`:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
<const>hintfull</const>
</edit>
</match>
<match target="font">
<edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

I do not find any unusual settings from `printenv` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg) for Xorg led me to the solution. It states

> The DPI of the X server is determined in the following manner:
>
> - The -dpi command line option has highest priority.
> - If this is not used, the DisplaySize setting in the X config file is used to derive the DPI, given the screen resolution.
> - If no DisplaySize is given, the monitor size values from DDC are used to derive the DPI, given the screen resolution.
> - If DDC does not specify a size, 75 DPI is used by default.

Based on that, I looked for "-dpi" and I found the problem with this:

```
grep -r '\-dpi' /etc/
/etc/sddm.conf:ServerArguments=-nolisten tcp -dpi 192
```

Removing "-dpi 192" from that line solved the issue.